# How do I change my login provider(s)?

Tags: support, faq, login

I no longer use the service that I originally used to register, and would like to change the service I use to log in, or at least add a second account.

Is this possible? How do I change my login provider or associate a backup method to log in?

> For more information, see "[How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: [Remove alternative OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid) has other useful info, too :)

Comment: If looking for how to change OpenID email, see - [How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/how-do-i-change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stack-exchange-openid)

Answer (score 102):

Yes, this is documented on the [Stack Overflow blog](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids) and in [the Help Center](/help/edit-logins).

You can add an unlimited number of logins of your choosing from the account page, by either going to [`meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) or by clicking "Settings" at the top of your profile → "Your Logins" at the left → "Add more logins...".

> [image: Add or remove logins]

If this prompts you to log in as a different user, then you probably already used that "new" way to log in earlier. In that case see [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

You can also remove credentials you no longer wish to be tied to your account from this screen.

#### Special cases

- If you are signing in with Google and want to add another Google account, see [here](/q/134379) for instructions.

Comment: My other login is still there though, when I log in using my other email, which I removed, it says "do you want to create an account with this email?" How can I completely remove that other email?

Comment: I created an email/password through the forgotten password link and I can login with it. However I am weary of removing my Google account link because it says it is bound to the "root" login (StackExchange). The wording might be throwing me off but is it safe to remove all OpenID login providers and be left only with email and password?