# Is it possible to change my OpenID here?

Tags: support, openid

My Gmail account was stolen, and if I close my browser I will lose my Stack Overfloww account.

What can I do?

Comment: Doesn't belong to SO, but meta. Yet, I don't know what you could do :/. Keep faith.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think this would work:

1. Create another OpenID (for instance at https://www.myopenid.com/)
2. Go into your user profile page at stackoverflow.com
3. Click the "new login" link, and follow the instructions to associate the new login with your newly created OpenID
4. Go back to your user profile page and swap the ID's so that the new ID is the primary one

I hope it works that way.

Edit: [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/) seem to confirm by belief.