# Decomissioning a website, how to get rid of an openid on the StackOverflow-sites?

Tags: support, openid

I have two OpenIDs associated with my SO-related sites, one for the "myOpenID" account, and one through my website, which is a delegate to my "myOpenID" account.

Since I'm getting rid of my website, which I never update, I'd like to remove the openid-account associated with my accounts that will no longer function.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove alternative OpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK no, but you can swap it so that it becomes the Secondary OpenID and never use it. Should someone register your website and set it up as your delegate again, they would still need to authenticate with your real OpenID provider.

By the way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31371/how-do-i-delete-my-alt-openid (not a real duplicate, but answered by Jeff)

Comment: The domain will still be mine, it's just the web-part that disappears, so nobody will be able to do that.

Comment: Since I've swapped my openid accounts, so that the myOpenID account is now the primary, what happens if I create a second openId account with another provider, for safety, and associates that with my SO account, which one will be replaced?

Comment: The primary one will be replaced, so swap the one you want to keep with your alternate then swap them back after registering your new one.

Comment: Just to add: Contacting team@so is always an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *delete* an OpenID, but you can *overwrite* it with another OpenID.

That would be my recommendation. If you absolutely must have an OpenID removed and do not want to overwrite it, you can always email us (via the address at the bottom of every page, of course..) and we can do it very easily.