# OpenID Delete account

Tags: support, openid

My OpenID is used through my email provider.

1) Why wasn't my URL recognized at OpenID Foundation.

2) I want to delete "alt openID" URL.

3) How do I delete the OpenID from being associated with my email provider such as Google or Yahoo.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove alternative OpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid)

Answer (score 1):

1: if you mean "why can't I re-use my openid at other sites", you are currently using gmail openid; with gmail, each target web-site gets a **different** openid, so you can't copy/paste the open id between sites in that case. If you mean "why doesn't my OpenID Foundation openid work?" then "pass" (I'm not involved in that...), but we can perhaps try to find out...

2: A moderator can do that, but I **strongly** suggest keeping an alternative id; occasionally the odd provider is unavailable for a short (or extended) duration

3: I'm a bit lost what you mean there, but ultimately... if you don't want your e-mail provider involved, then don't use  gmail/yahoo as your openid provider

Comment: re 2: I have an SE account and an Area51 account I'd like to separate, but the Area51 account has my SE OpenID as its alt id

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to your profile page

2) Click the delete link beside alt openid :-)

[image]