# Please implement a way to remove an OpenID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login)

There is a **support** question how to do it and it has 31 upvotes: [Remove alternative OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808)

however,, the question is answered with a (very complete) "can't be done" answer.

So I thought I would ask a **feature-request** question can the system be modified to allow it.

If you upvote this.. please also upvote the one I linked to so that we do not have to start with zero votes and we can instead start with 31.

The reason **I** want to do this is because I want to have two separate sets of associated SE sites and I want to share my personal (example cooking SE) information to local contacts without sharing our technical information (for example SE, SF)

I would remove associations but then I lose the inbox and copy profile features

Comment: Now that you added the feature-request label to pek's question.. does that mean the developers will consider implementing the feature? @Jon

Comment: Well, it was a case of a question where it asks "How can I do this? If I can't, I want to have that ability." So for things where the functionality doesn't exist, those questions are categorized as feature requests. In terms of duplicates, this question covers the same ground as the other, regardless of the tags. It's the content that matters.