# How often are new SO versions deployed?

Tags: support

In [Remove Alternative openID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid) it is said that this feature will be included in next SO deployment. So, how often are new SO versions deployed?

Comment: Almost everyday I far as I seen, and sometimes many times a day.

Comment: You can watch the revision number at the bottom of the screen to see when a new build goes out; meta is on rev 2011.4.23.5, so there's been 5 builds today

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless it's an odd week (when the team is at MIX, or holidays for example) we're usually building every day, and often several times a day.  To be accurate, we're probably even building then, since we're all a bit insane.

As a general rule, we don't build during peak traffic. We try to cause as little interruption as possible.  If there's a high-impact bug or change that needs to be fixed/made, we'll make an exception.

Comment: also, meta.so gets built first in all cases so it is always bleeding edge.

Comment: Does that mean there is a new feature or bug fix every day?

Comment: @RichardTingle yep, lately we're averaging about 5 builds a day so deployment of new features/changes/fixes is pretty rapid...and that's just the websites.