# Stack Exchange release management

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, development

I saw this thread: [How often are new SO versions deployed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88602/how-often-are-so-new-versions-deployed)

- You are using CI and unit tests, right?
- Do you do anything more before pushing out new releases?
- What kind of guidelines do you follow when writing unit tests?

Basically, I'm wondering how you make sure that each release is good enough.

Comment: To apply the job there?

Comment: Jeff explains in depth  how the software development process at SO works in [his profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood). (scroll down the box). Oh, and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69297/was-revival-and-reanimator-timed-for-halloween)

Comment: hehe, stabilt svar Pekka.

Comment: What are these "unit tests" you speak of???  Also just in case there's any title confusion from the question title, stackexchange.com is a different code base (as are careers and area 51), they're all deployed independently.

Comment: BWAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA! hee hee hee hoo boy you can sure crack a joke

Comment: @Arjan I had a long unbroken line, but deleted that and added one with spaces so it would linebreak without messing up the page format.  Using FF 4 it appeared fine to me, but I suppose it messed someone up somewhere, because it indeed has been edited to remove the majority of my LOLing.  It's a one-off joke, though, so it's not as though it matters.

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not seeing those spaces, @Adam. ;-) But on the other hand: it's nice that the Firefox bug is consistent then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Herding Code 110](http://herdingcode.com/?p=315) just came out today; it's an interview with two SO developers ([Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) and [Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon)). They discuss some of their process:

> - How do you share data when developing with a remote team? Geoff talks about how they started with the Database Project type, but moved to SQL scripts, ending with a migration tool. Jon gets to say “idempotent”.
> - Geoff and Jarrod talk about how they’ve moved form Subversion to Mercurial.
> - Jon asks how code moves from local development to a production server. Geoff talks about the build and deployment process.
> - Kevin asks how much the process has changed over the years.
> - Geoff talks about how features first hit Meta, then the “others” tier (everything but StackOverflow), then to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 13):

We practice FDD: faith driven development. We *believe* our code will work.

Answer (score 7):

The software development process is very much test-orientated as I believe that SO engages tens of thousands of regression testers, who are happy to be paid with virtual currency.