# Cannot remove logins anymore?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid, login

I just noticed that the login portion of my StackOverflow profile is different than it was back when I joined the site.

It now lists some email addresses, and indicates I can sign in with any Google, Facebook, Yahoo or Stack Exchange account that lists the specified email addresses. Then it also lists OpenIDs that can be used to log into the site.

This is an improvement, since relatively new users can sign in with any of the popular services without having to remember which one they originally used, and you are no longer limited to just two OpenIDs being associated with your account.

However, it seems like there is no longer any way to remove any Logins from the lists. This is a regression. As mentioned in a comment on [Remove Alternate OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19808/remove-alternative-openid), this is a security issue. If an OpenID Provider goes rogue, or it goes under and an evil entity buys the domain, I should be able to remove it from my account.

Am I missing something, or does removal of Logins need to be re-implemented?

Comment: As for going rogue: [MyOpenID account mysteriously vanished](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see somebody finally noticed our new login screen.

[image]

We'll be rolling this out to the rest of the sites in the network (Area 51, StackExchange.com, maybe Careers) over the next few weeks.

Until we're done, we've disabled credential deletion.  Since we're still working kinks out, it'd be a bit unpleasant if credentials were disappearing out from under us while we're debugging the myriad OpenID edge cases.

<del>Once we're confident everything is good to go, we'll re-enable credential deletion.  So, [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) basically.</del>

---

This has been enabled now.

[image]

Comment: Sounds fine. My main concern was that credential deletion was disabled indefinitely. Anybody with an urgent need to remove credentials could contact the StackExchange team. My needs are by no means urgent, so I'll just wait.

Comment: I don't have this option, was this feature disabled again? I'm presented with a window like the top screenshot, not the bottom one.

Comment: How do I get access to the window that you show in the second half of your answer? Sorry for resurrecting the post.

Comment: @KannappanSampath - click "my logins" when looking at your own profile page, it's in the [upper tabs](http://i.imgur.com/P4QKv.png) (note some of those things are dev/mod-only).

Comment: I noticed that if I go to stack exchange.com then the option is missing, but if I view my profile in one of the specific sites (subdomains?), then I have the option to remove.

Comment: and a year+ later.. i had a dog of a time hunting down the delete credentials links. this post continued to confuse me, as it had me convinced the "privilege" was removed (temporarily or not).

FINALLY, relief. for me, the KEY was associating @KevenMontrose's "upper tabs" png to where my eye-balls were focusing. the menu in his image show's the "flair" item, which is unique--helping me drill down to the correct menu.

from a ux perspective, there's enough redundancy on these profile pages to convince oneself she's doing it right—-but getting nowhere.

Comment: Does removing these logins apply on all the SE/SO sites, like career, latex, ... ? Or do I need to remove them separately?

Comment: I want to remove my Facebook login and leave only a Stack Exchange login.  I do *not* have the red X's pictured above in my UI.  Please help.

Comment: @MatthewBriggs I removed it for you. Let me know if you're still having problems.

Comment: Thank you @AnnaLear !

Comment: Second @Randy6T9's comment and this is the advice I received from the Stack Exchange team today: "It's not a red (x) any more, it's just the text "remove". Also, you can't do this on stackexchange.com for some reason. Just use a profile from another site (e.g. Stack Overflow)."

Comment: And does this issue fixed now? I see that I still cannot delete the unneeded logins...

Comment: As well as I cannot edit StackExchange login. Cannot change email.

Comment: @Suncatcher email is the very key of the login, makes sense that it can't be changed. Just create new login and add it or ask for a merge.