# How do I delete a login

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot remove logins anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/cannot-remove-logins-anymore)

I am abandoning my current position at a company who's email account I used to log into all my stack exchange sites. I'd like to remove that login and add a new one. I can see not being able to remove the only one, but I'd like to remove the old one after adding a new one.

This is not the same as "removing alt openid" since I am trying to remove a primary openid. I have already revoked access from within my google account, but I would still like to disassociate all my stack exchange sites from the old google account.

Comment: +1 I agree. I did not see that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (by your hand). I'd like to have such option, too (to change primary OpenId). There will probably be someone who will delete it for you.

Comment: I'm guessing this is by-design to make it harder to steal someone's account in such a way that you can't get it back. Changing your primary OpenId is probably rare enough that it can be handled manually by a mod or a dev.

Comment: [`[status-planned]`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/cannot-remove-logins-anymore) (err, that's a link)