# Trouble with Area 51 Login

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, google-chrome

I went to look at proposals on area51 today, and I keep getting a popup that says that I have been logged in and am being redirected to the main page. It redirects me, but it doesn't actually log me in. I am using my Google account to sign in, and trying to do this in Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and then logging back in? Are you using a VPN? I've seen logins (admittedly, on chat) get weird if I was on a VPN.

Comment: Tried all of the above, and made sure I wasn't using a VPN. Also tried closing the browser, reopening it, and trying again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of deploying our [new centralized login scheme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/cannot-remove-logins-anymore/104226#104226) revealed some bugs when we got to Area 51.  Looks like you were affected.

It should be fixed now.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. I try to login with my Google OpenID and get `Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified. `