# How do I remove an OpenID?

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot remove logins anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/cannot-remove-logins-anymore)

Since the recent changes to the login system I can't see any obvious way to remove one of my OpenID logins. Where is that featire hidden now?

Comment: duplicate : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104222/162863

Answer (score 1):

It's been temporarily disabled while the new system is tested, according Kevin Montrose in [Cannot remove logins anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104222/cannot-remove-logins-anymore):

> I see somebody finally noticed our new login screen.
>
> Until we're done, we've disabled credential deletion. Since we're still working kinks out, it'd be a bit unpleasant if credentials were disappearing out from under us while we're debugging the myriad OpenID edge cases.
>
> Once we're confident everything is good to go, we'll re-enable credential deletion.