# How do I remove an OpenID or login?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

How do I remove login credentials (emails or OpenIDs) from my account?

> For more information, see "[How do I add or move login credentials from my account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

---

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq)

Comment: I don't see why there need to be separate FAQs for changing vs. removing login providers, given that it's the same page and process for both. I've picked [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers) for the master since it has a more up-to-date screenshot and answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You must go to any Q&A site, such as Stack Overflow, then to your profile → Edit profile and settings → My logins. You can also visit the page directly by going to [`meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current).

You will now see the remove button, like the below:

> [image: Remove logins]

**Note: changing your login methods on one site will change your login methods for all sites you currently use.** <sub>([source](/a/268949))</sub>

Comment: A slight annoyance: after removing one ID, the page has to be refreshed before removing the second to avoid the " ... not found Please refresh the page." notification.