# How can I remove an OpenID from a Stack Overflow account?

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login)

How can I remove an OpenID from a Stack Overflow account?

Comment: Thanks Arjan for pointing out that thread. From the discussion I don't think it's possible.

Comment: disappointed to find out that you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Flag any of your own posts and ask a moderator, specifying which one you want removed.

Comment: Thanks Kop. I will contact the moderator.

Comment: AFAIK mods can't do this.  Or, at least, I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Will: I think they can, I saw Bill the Lizard posting that he did it, but maybe because he is a dev? My guess is that you would go to the user's profile and click remove somewhere but I assume you already tried that