# How do I detach an email address from my Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login)

I have two email addresses bound to my Stack Exchange account here. How can I detach one of them?

Comment: @animuson, yes, but it seems I can't detach email which is bound to an openid. After detaching the email, the old account shows up when I login with the detached email address.