# What happens when I remove the Stack Exchange app from Facebook?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login

I use my Facebook account to log-in into Stack Exchange sites. What would happen if I accidentally remove Stack Exchange app from my Facebook account? Do my all reputation points, Questions & Answers get deleted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you have another way to log in, it's fine--you won't lose anything.

If you remove all your logins, you may be unable to log in, though you will stay logged in for the duration of your browser session.

Check out [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)  and [How do I remove an OpenID or login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login) on how you remove/change your OpenID logins. I suggest you add a [StackExchange login](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register).