# Removing Facebook login cause removal of other OpenID

Tags: bug, openid, login

Removing OpenID login from profile "My Logins" page cause the remove of other OpenID's. In my case: additional remove of Stack Exchange and Google, so, only LaunchPad is left.

Removing LaunchPad did not affect other OpenID's.

[image]

Comment: From your comment on the answer sounds like you ask the wrong question. You should change this to report a bug where removing Facebook OpenID cause Google and Stack Exchange to be removed as well, and tag this as a [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Converted into the bug.

Comment: Nice, much better now. This sounds like pretty severe issue so you can also submit a support ticket [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) explaining the same thing. (Here on Meta such reports might not get proper attention)

Comment: I have the same issue. I added a Facebook login which uses my googlemail address. Now if I remove the facebook login, the googlemail login will be removed too. Then we re-adding my googlemail login, the Facebook login is revived too. :(

Answer (score 1):

You didn't follow that instruction.

1. Open your **profile page**. (You are opening your **network** profile page. (guessing from the image you posted.))
2. Click the "my logins" link near the top.
3. Click the "remove" to the right of the login you wish to remove.

<sub>PS: I don't know whether we can remove logins from network profile or not. But as per [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22224/187824) you can remove it from your profile page.</sub>

Comment: This didn't help. It keep removing **all** my OpenID except for LaunchPad.

Comment: @m0nhawk - Isn't there any option like *remove* to the right side of LaunchPad?