# My Google-based connection ID not usable, Atlassian Crowd problem

Tags: support

So, I have a Stack Exchange account. When I first created it a couple of years back, I used my "Google" credentials. Fine.
Then late last year I began work with a company which uses Atlassian Crowd to manage IDs and logins, and at some point my Stack Exchange account must have become associated with my id at that company.
Now my Stack Exchange account is inaccessible.

But it does exist.

Is there some way to reconnect to my Stack Exchange id?

Comment: Note that I had to create a new Stack Exchange id in order to post this question.

Comment: I.e. [send an email to SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact). Don't forget to include links to the profile pages of any relevant account(s). They'll help you work through it.

Comment: Thanks @JasonC and others... the SE email addresses available only seem related to "talent", and not anything related to help or support.

Comment: If you click "send an email to SE" in my previous comment you will be taken to the contact form. You can also click "contact us" in the footer of any page. Also the instructions in the answer I linked to describe this as well. Granted perhaps it is not an "email", per se, but, whatever. There's a moral here, though: You should click links more often. :)

Comment: Thanks @JasonC again. I've now started that process, let's see how it pans out. If it turns out to be a simple extension, or the same, then I'll mark it as being the same/solved/whatever.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login