# How to change OpenID

Tags: support, openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-provider)

I know its a silly question, but can anyone tell me how can I change my OpenID on Stack Overflow. Thanks

Comment: but how to change my open id is still an answer waiting question