# How to access SO with multiple openid accounts?

Tags: support, openid, login

Recently, MyOpenID went off the air, meaning that I couldn't log on to SO. While trawling the net for information, it appears that some people have multiple openid accounts for allowing them to access their SO account.

How do we go about setting this up? Can a single SO account log in with *either* of two openid accounts?

Note that I'm talking about a *single* SO account, not a duplicate. I just want to avoid the possibility of not being able to log in if my one openid provider goes bad (or worse, belly up, although I assume in that case, the SO admins could weave some database magic and associate my account with a different openid provider).

But, in terms of a temporary outage of openid provider, I figure having MyOpenID and Google (and possibly even *more* for extra backup) would be a good idea but I have no idea how to set this up in SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change my OpenID provider?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-provider)

Comment: I don't want to _change_ providers, I want _multiple_ providers in case of outage.

Comment: The answer on that FAQ says how to add a provider

Comment: I've edited the text of the proposed dupe question to include second OpenIDs to match the existing answer and this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your profile page (assuming you're already logged-in), there should be a link titled "my logins". Follow that, and you can additional OpenIDs to your account using , then "add more logins...".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a webspace under your control, you can also use delegated OpenId. Just put these two lines into the `<HEAD>` section of any HTML file on the internet that is under your control:

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server"> 
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://USERNAME.myopenid.com">
```

The URL of this file is now an OpenId.

I do exactly this for my OpenId. So while I usually log in through MyOpenId, the OpenId associated with my Stack Overflow account is a URL on my own domain.

So when MyOpenId went down yesterday, I just signed up with MyId, and replaced the two lines above with

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://server.myid.net/server">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://USERNAME.myid.net">
```

until MyOpenId was up again. So even though for a few hours I had a different OpenId provider, to Stack Overflow my OpenId had not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes either OpenID will log on that user. I use my website with WordPress as my main OpenID which is http://www.bens-wiki.co.cc/ and in case I lose it I will still have Google which is my secound but I usally log on with my Gmail so I don't have to type my website in.