# My OpenID is busted, so I can't log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, openid

When I try to log in to StackExchange with my openID, I get this mess:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The openid.return_to parameter (http://android.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=cf97...795&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://id.mayfirst.org/abh) does not match the actual URL (http://android.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=cf97...795&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://id.mayfirst.org/abh&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https://id.mayfirst.org/openid/provider&openid.identity=https://id.mayfirst.org/abh&openid.claimed_id=https://id.mayfirst.org/abh&openid.return_to=http://android.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=cf97...795&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%253A%252F%252Fid.mayfirst.org%252Fabh&openid.response_nonce=2012-01-03T01:10:44ZNHDM&openid.assoc_handle=2012-01-03T01:10:44ZFVZB&openid.sreg.nickname=abh&openid.sreg.email=&s=cf97...795&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://id.mayfirst.org/abh&openid.signed=op_endpoint,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,identity,claimed_id&openid.sig=+sP8d...HWSQ4=) the request was made with.
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to access that login anymore. I can't figure out whether the issue is with Stack Exchange or my OpenID provider, but my OpenID provider hasn't been able to resolve it and it only happens on stack exchange.

Ideas?

Comment: FWIW, my accounts have been merged. So my personal problem has been solved. The larger OpenID failure remains. I could call the question "answered" even though it hasn't exactly been explained.

Answer (score 4):

Please take this opportunity to [set up multiple OpenID providers for your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77061/how-to-access-so-with-multiple-openid-accounts), so you can always get back to your account if one provider dies or ceases providing log in information for Stack Exchange sites or throws away your user data for some reason.

Comment: Excellent advice; I just added Facebook and Google log ins to my SE account, which had a MyOpenID log in already. +!

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced that as well and found out that it was because I was trying to log in via https://android.stackexchange.com (mind the S in HTTPS).

Once I changed to http://android.stackexchange.com (and put the whole stackexchange-network on my https-whitelist) the login via openid worked again.

I also saw "http://android.stack..." in the error message but my guess is you got to the login page via https.

EDIT: interestingly enough I just tried that at https://apple.stackexchange.com and openid login worked there. So my guess is either that was a temporary issue or the apple-site is not affected.

Comment: No dice. I get the same behavior on both http and https.

Comment: This worked for me, though disable https is a bit disappointing.

Comment: By the way: this error still persists. I just experienced this on ux.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write to Stack Exchange support from the email address associated with my original account and have them merge the two accounts. So I still don't know what's wrong with Mayfirst's OpenID but I do have access to my account again.