# Merging two accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access SO with multiple openid accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77061/how-to-access-so-with-multiple-openid-accounts)

I use my facebook account to log in to stackoverflow. However I can not use this or yahoo or google account to log in from my workplace as these are blocked. I am thinking of creating a new stackexchange login. Is there any provision to merge my facebook and stackexchange login ?

Comment: Go to your profile, "My logins", "Add more logins", "Click here to add a stack exchange account"

Comment: Your work blocks Google?  How the heck do you get anything done?

Comment: Bing is the new hotness @jmo

Comment: I wouldn't be able to work there. With all due respect, everyone needs a job, but that would be a real tough pill for me to swallow as a dev.

Comment: @jmort253 No, but you can not log in into your account. You can just use the search feature.