# Log In With Stack Exchange instead of myopenid.com, how could I?

Tags: support, login

I'm currently logging in with `myopenid.com`, but I'd like to move to log in with SE.
How can I do it?
Do I have to sign up and then link the accounts?

edit: I tried to register in SE but it asked for a weird (IMHO) requirement of having like 8 unique characters in the password? what site asks for that?
I hate sites that impose rules on password creation, like this one or digits and mixed case, I know it's for security, but as I always choose certain type of passwords so I can remember them and sites that impose rules break that.
Anyway my passwords despite not following intricate security rules are secure, and anyway nobody would find anything much valuable should they break into one of my logins.

So I'll stick to my good old openID. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a "Copy {Site} login credentials to all Stack Exchange accounts" button on the **account tab** of your user page now:

[image]

Comment: whoo hoo!  *finally!*

Answer (score 4):

Yes. [Register an account](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) on the Stack Exchange openid page and then go through the process of adding an additional openid to your account ([here is a FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)).

As far as I understand, there isn't a way yet of being able to replicate your openid information to all the sites so you will need to add your Stack Exchange openid to each Stack Exchange site that you use if you want to login with that account. However, once you've logged in on one site, you can then login on other sites if your accounts are linked.

Comment: Actually, as of very recently (like yesterday or today, I think), you can now push OpenID information from the accounts tab to all associated accounts.

Comment: @waiwai933 AWESOME!!!!!!!!! I've wanted this for so long