# Logging in via Stack Exchange instead of via my old OpenID provider (Wordpress)

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid

I was actually browsing to meta.stackexchange since my question concerns the entire network, but I was redirected here so I guess it's alright to ask this question here.

My problem is the following:

I've first created my stackoverflow account using my wordpress.com OpenID, but I then associated my real e-mail address with this account. Under my account settings I can see my correct e-mail address and my openid account (xxx.wordpress.com).

Now I wanted to signup to scifi.stackexchange.com. So I clicked StackExchange as my OpenID provider (since I have an account here). I entered the e-mail address which is displayed in my account and my password. However I can't log-in/register this way. It keeps saying that my e-mail address is not recognized.

Now I would prefer to set-up my account as following:

- un-associate my wordpress.com account (I hardly use it, and it's
  cumbersome to log in to)
- Set my StackExchange account as my OpenID provider
- Log in to StackExchange using my e-mail+password
- Log in/Register to StackExchange associated sites using the Stack
  Exchange OpenID.

Is this possible, or am I stuck to using my wordpress account forever now? I would really love to deleted my wordpress account and unfortunately SE is stopping me from doing this now :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more browsing I found this answer:

[How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

In that answer it seems to be possible to use stackexchange itself for login, however when I go the mylogins page now the stackexchange option has disappeared:

**Old version** with stack exchange option
[image: Old version with stack exchange]

**New Version** without stack exchange option
[image: New Version that removed SE]

However you can still use the manual URL option: https://openid.stackexchange.com to use stackexchange as your openId provider. However why the button was removed I dont know :/.