# OpenID - Google to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, openid, google-openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

I currently use a google account for OpenID login but this account will be shutting down at some point soon so I need to somehow transfer my details over to another account.
Is there a simple way to do this without losing any reputation or medals from the existing account?

Comment: Definite duplicate, sorry, I didn't come across that result on my searches.