# How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I registered my Stack Overflow account using the Stack Exchange OpenID provider. I later changed my e-mail, but I cannot change the e-mail address associated with my OpenID for some reason. Why is that, and how do I change it? I logged in to Stack Exchange and it lets me change my password, but never my e-mail.

Comment: I asked this question after the [initial trial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/help-us-test-and-vet-stackid-stack-exchange-openid), on a now-deleted answer. Kevin replied "Also, no, your account is tied directly to your e-mail address by design.". I do not know if this is still the case, but I will point him at this new question.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to change your email address. Just follow this guide: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/177496)

Comment: @covanova yeah you're right, you can change the stackoverflow e-mail in that way. however the open id e-mail cannot be changed I think. so for example you can remove the openid association from your account and register another openid association (that has a different e-mail)

Comment: @test : It seems that my previous comment is confusing. Let me rephrase it. The _OpenID Email address_ cannot be changed. The **link** I posted tells you how to change your associated _OpenID account_ to a new one, without losing your _reputation_, _badges_, and so on.

Comment: @MarcGravell : As myopera shut down, how I can merge new accounts now ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You cannot change the e-mail address attached to your openid.stackexchange account, by design.

If you've lost access to the e-mail you registered with initially, create a new openid.stackexchange account and either add it to your Stack Overflow account (via your profile page, if you're still logged in) or create a new Stack Overflow account and email us via the Contact link so we can merge the two accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I re-registered with another e-mail and then I added that to my StackOverflow account. Then I clicked the 'swap' link in my profile to switch the two OpenIDs. Then I deleted the old one.

Comment: Does this method still work? Each time I am trying to proceed, I cannot enter any alternative account. It goes straight back to home page of SE.

Comment: Why is this "by design"?  People commonly change email addresses and nearly all websites allow you to change the email address associated with your profile.  Why does StackExchange feel that they shouldn't allow it in their system?

Comment: I'm not seeing the 'swap' link mentioned by @test .  Is this feature still available?

Comment: Jeez! You can't change your e-mail address on your StackExchange OpenID. The password requirements on StackExchange OpenIDs are more strict than for other OpenIDs. Where will this madness end???

Comment: What if you _do_ still have access to the e-mail you registered with initially?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working; after creating a new StackExchange openID, login to Stack exchange with old one, then profile>myLogins>addMoreLogins>loginwithstackexchange. It then doesn't ask for login details because I'm already logged in with my old OpenID

Comment: 1. I want to remove my current email from my account/profile/openID.
2. I am ready to create a new account, then merge it with current profile and then get rid of the old openID/email.

Shall I be able to retain my StackExchange OpenID vanity URL if I do this?

Comment: Does "swap" currently work? There seem to be conflicting answers here.

Comment: `You cannot change the e-mail address … by design. … create a new account … email us via the Contact link so we can merge the two accounts.` So the design is to be unnecessarily and highly inconvenient, cumbersome, and time-consuming? ಠ_ఠ

Comment: Duplicates and "related" questions to this abound, but I still have to login with an e-mail address that doesn't exist.  How long till someone makes a code change that destroys my account after a notification bounces?  AND, I created another account with an address that does exist (months ago), but now that I have forgotten that password, the reset password tool claims that the address is not associated with any account.

Comment: IS THIS STILL THE BEST WAY TO DO THIS IN 2017? Or is there another newer way? I'm asking because so many people seem to be so unhappy about this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Stupidest design choice ever.  Let me guess, someone on the team HATES surrogate keys and argued that email address would be a perfectly fine natural key.  I guess it never occurred to anyone that 1) emails can change (and you may not have access to the old one) and 2) some people DON'T want FB or Google to be the keys to everything about them.

Comment: I just can't believe this!

Comment: Maybe this answer should be rewritten to explain it more carefully, because at first glance people think that this means it's impossibru to change stackexchange account's associated e-mail address, which is false of course. People don't care that you can't change e-mail address associated with a StackExchange OpenID, because that's not what was asked in the question.

Comment: StackExchange really needs to come up with a simpler solution to allow users to change their primary email address. Hope such a thing is available soon.

Comment: I'm currently in the middle of switching internet providers and so I'm migrating all my old logins away from my old provider. But because of this complicated process, I may not be able to switch it off before the next billing cycle. (Cue world's smallest violin.) I have to believe that SE support has spent more time handling these cases manually than it would take to fix it programmatically by now... If someone fixes this, it'll probably be too late for me, but I think the next person to deal with it will be very grateful. It's especially jarring because SE is such a great site otherwise.

Comment: OpenID is being phased out. You can add a new login here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

Answer (score 25):

Managed to add new Stack Exchange OpenID to my Stack Overflow account this way:

1. Create new stackexchange account
2. Login on https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login to reach https://openid.stackexchange.com/user and click the "Use your own URL to log in" link
3. Then copy the copy the url from the second entry similar to: `https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx`
4. Go to https://superuser.com/users/login-add?ssrc=login and add the openid link from above to the OpenID field and click "Add Credential"
5. Enter your username and password for the new stachexchange account and click add/confirm when prompted
6. From https://superuser.com/users/mylogins/ you can now delete the old stackechange account with the old email address

Comment: Thank you this worked. For anyone having problems with last step, simply click on your avatar with badges in the upper right corner, chose "Edit Profile & Settings" from left tab bar and under SITE SETTINGS choose "My Logins"

Comment: does deleting the old account also deletes reputation and badges earned?

Comment: Not for me.....

Comment: This no longer works.  The "https://superuser.com/users/mylogins/" page doesn't exist now.

Comment: @LS, it does exist now when I click the link.

Comment: Nowadays it seems to be a bit simpler, although still not really as obvious as it could be: the "My logins > add more logins..." page no longer accepts an OpenID URL, but it has inputs for an e-mail address and a password. Turns out that you can just use that form to add a new e-mail/password combination and afterwards it should be possible to remove the old e-mail/password under "My logins" page.

Comment: Has the URL changed? On https://openid.stackexchange.com/user I get “Not Found
This page could not be found.”

Comment: @OleV.V., it's still there, you just need to login, from https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login

Answer (score 6):

Managed to do this using process similar to [petersv's answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/280335/333476), but used an outside login as the in-between account.  (first three steps from petersv's answer)

1. Create new stackexchange account
2. Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/user and click the "Use your own URL to log in" link
3. Then copy the copy the url from the second entry similar to: `https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx`
4. Log out
5. Login with your old stackexchange account
6. Goto your profile, goto 'Edit Profile & Settings', then 'My Logins'
7. Assuming your old stackexchange account is the only way you can log in, create a new login mechanism via Gmail, Facebook, Yahoo, etc.
8. Now that you have a new way to login, remove your old stack exchange ID as a login mechanism via the 'remove' button.
9. Click on 'add more logins', now you can use the openid URL from above to create a new login with your new stackexchange account.

Comment: So... with 3 extra steps you achieved the exact same as me? ;)

Comment: Your steps didn't quite work for me.  In hindsight, not being a member of superuser was perhaps one part of the issue?  The link in step 6 didn't work for me either (even when adjusting for communities I am in).  Not sure why it's different for me.

Comment: Sure, now I understand. You added a new OpenID you your old Stack Exchange account.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this using Albert Chu’s and petersv’s comments as guides.

I created a new account account at https://openid.stackexchange.com/. This account was then automatically associated with my old account. My guess is that this was automated because of cookies from a previous log-in into the old account.

A notable point of confusion is that one must access the “My Logins” link from a Stack Exchange community site like Graphic Design Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, or Super User to delete an old email address, **not** https://stackexchange.com/ where one would most expect to be able to edit their account. There’s no “remove” link if you access “My Logins” from the core site.

Furthermore, after deleting an old email address, the associated Stack Exchange OpenID account and its vanity URL still exist at https://openid.stackexchange.com/, albeit separate from the new account. If you wish to assign that URL to the new account, you’ll need to log into the old account and delete the vanity URL, and then log into the new account and assign the released URL to it.

This also means you’ll have a dangling account each time you need to change your email address since the old accounts apparently can’t be deleted.