# Changing email address for the whole network

Tags: support, login, email, network-profile

I'm able to change the email for Stack Overflow, but for login, it still asks for my old mail. Checking <kbd>Network Profile</kbd> > <kbd>My Logins</kbd>, the old email still appears. How do I fix this?

Furthermore, on the bottom of the question page, the email field for "Send me new responses to my posts via email" had a *very* old email.

Comment: If looking for how to change OpenID email, see - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/how-do-i-change-the-email-address-associated-with-my-stack-exchange-openid

Answer (score 4):

Hit the "remove" link next to your email. Removing old email, done.

Now, create a new login with your new email!

Ta-dah!

Comment: Between remove and create, if something happens, will I be unable to access my account?

Comment: You can still use your original Stack Exchange login.

Comment: @aniOSdeveloper you can't remove all the logins, if there's only one, you can't remove it.