# How do I change my e-mail on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, email, facebook, email-addresses

How to change email from Stack Overflow to another email?
How to unlink your Facebook account?
I tried to unlink it from the Facebook application and even delete it from the Stack Overflow profile, once it was removed from both sites, I log in as a new user with the email and the same profile appears.

In Stack Exchange, there is no way to modify it.

I looked into this question's solutions, but they do not work: [How can I change my Stack Exchange login email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247605/how-can-i-change-my-stack-exchange-login-email)

Comment: The original email I used to sign up to SO years ago is no longer working, and I can't find any way to update it without opening a new account login and adding that to my existing: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102469/299956