# Change OpenID on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, openid, stackexchange.com

[this is not a dupe of **[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)**]

When I originally registered at stackexchange.com I used MyOpenID as my provider, which I have subsequently tossed aside.  I would like to switch my stackexchange.com profile over to Google but there seems no mechanism for doing so.  Am I just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a recent round of network-wide authentication refactoring/improvements, all your accounts (i.e. Q&A sites, Area 51, and Stack Exchange) use the same login credentials. So, adding an OpenId to one of your accounts is actually equivalent to adding it to *all* of your accounts.

That said, the "my logins" popup was just added to stackexchange.com, so the "add more logins" UI is exposed on stackexchange.com as well now.

Comment: Perfect, works great now.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add your Google account as a login for your Stack Exchange account by going to your profile, clicking on "my logins" and then "add more logins...". Removing your old OpenID isn't possible *at the moment* because the login system is being tweaked, but it should be possible soon, in the same location.

[image]

Comment: This is for stackexchange.com, not MSO or any of the other Q&A sites themselves.  There is no `my logins` when viewing your profile on stackexchange.com.

Comment: @squillman: I'm not certain, but if you login to Stack Overflow or any other site using that login, and then follow these steps, it should be equivalent. I didn't create my account on Stack Exchange, I created it on Stack Overflow, but I've added login methods on Stack Overflow and been able to use them on Stack Exchange later.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but when I try to login on stackexchange.com using Google it doesn't recognize my Google OpenID and tries to create a new stackexchange.com account.