# Can't login with Google account auth while logged in a different gmail account

Tags: support, login, google-openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

When I log into stackoverflow using foo@gmail.com, it redirects me to a gmail page, I then type in the password of foo@gmail.com, then I am logged into stackoverflow all right.

The problem is when I am already logged into gmail using bar@gmail.com. Then in another tab I try to log into stackoverflow using my foo@gmail.com account. I get redirected to a gmail page asking if I want to log into stackoverflow using bar@gmail.com, even though I typed foo@gmail.com into stackoverflow's login.

So I have to logout from bar@gmail before I can log into foo@stackoverflow. After I am logged into stackoverflow, I can log back into gmail using a different account.

Is this by design? This is impractical.

Is there something I can do to workaround this?

Comment: It sounds like google's bug to me. More accurately it is probably a _feature_ of using their SSO.

Comment: Doesn't having multiple active gmail accounts violate the terms of use anyway? Perhaps this is thier way of telling you consolidate or find another service.

Comment: This is sad. I can't go on like this. Maybe I can switch my stackoverflow account to just a username/password auth?

Comment: Oh we responded simultaneously. No, I multiple gmail accounts are fine. Beside, maybe it is not my own account, when I am borrowing the computer to check something on stackoverflow while my friend is logged in gmail.

Comment: Even still, I doubt there's anything SE can do anything about the way Google implements OpenID.

Comment: I see... Then how can I change my account to use another type of auth? I checked "accounts" and "my logins" but there is nothing that can be changed.

Comment: Logout, [signup for a new SE user account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login#create-account), then log back in with your gmail account and add the newly created login in _my logins_.

Comment: Better yet just click on the [click here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login?noauto=true&returlUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent#create-account) link under _To create a new Stack Exchange account_ on the _add more logins_ screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll do that.
(why the -1 btw?)

Comment: @M.Babcock  Gmail infact has a facility for staying signed in to multiple accounts. It also lets you tie accounts together such that you can send an email from one account while logged in on the other. So nope, not against ToS

Comment: On an unrelated note, this isn't a duplicate of the "Possible Duplicate" question at all. It's barely related. Bad tagging.