# Login with a different Google account

Tags: support, login, google-chrome

I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125537/cant-login-with-google-account-auth-while-logged-in-a-different-gmail-account) and the [one it links to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125537/cant-login-with-google-account-auth-while-logged-in-a-different-gmail-account). My question is related but different.

At the office, I use a [Google Apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_for_Work) account that uses [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail). I already have a personal Stack Exchange account based on an original me@gmail.com account.

At the office, the Stack Exchange login page will not let go of the Google Apps account for login. It wants to create a new account based on that when I want to log in.

I removed Stack Exchange cookies and the cookie to stackauth.com. Then I go to **login** > google. It brings up the office Google information with **confirm your new account**. I didn't tell it "sign up", I told it "log in".

Chrome version: 42.0.2311.135

Comment: Incognito defeats the purpose. At that point I may as well just use a different browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been jackin with this for a week trying not to post, and soon as I post i see a question in the 'related' bar that 1) didn't pop when I was making the post title and 2) didn't pop out of google when searching around. it didn't answer, but it gave me an idea that lead to a fix. I wouldn't have found it if I didn't make a post.

So here's how to fix it.

1. Go to your google accounts page.
   From gmail for example: Click Name in upper right > account > Connected apps and services > Account permissions.
2. Stack Exchange will be on this list. Click/hilite it.
3. Right sidebar > Revoke access

NOW when you go to SE login and click google, it will ask you for google creds.

Comment: This helped me to solve the problem. However, it seems Google has updated their settings since this was posted. I found it by clicking the Google Account circle at the upper right of any Google website -> My Account -> Apps with account access (under "Sign-in & security") -> MANAGE APPS -> Stack Exchange -> REMOVE ACCESS

Answer (score 3):

They've changed it again, you have to go to any Google website -> Manage Your Google Account -> Security -> Signing in to other sites -> Stack Exchange -> REMOVE ACCESS –

Comment: Google website -> Manage Your Google Account -> Security -> **Signing in with Google** (under `Signing in to other sites` section) -> Stack Exchange -> REMOVE ACCESS