# Alternate openid login?

Tags: support, openid, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

My Blogger account is going away at the end of the month, but I use it to login to my StackOverflow account.  I want to have another OpenId for logging into my StackOverflow and have it go to my same account here (aneccodeal).  However, when I tried to add another opanid login ('add more logins' under 'my logins') it seems to create an entirely new StackOverflow account (user445366) with a reputation of only 1 (like starting over again).

How does one go about associating another OpenID with an existing account?

Comment: Please rewrite the title to indicate you're having problems. Related: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers), which seems to be what you actually tried.

Comment: (And, as an aside: Stack Overflow likes a space in its name!)

Comment: [That account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/445366/user445366) was definitely not just created... As noted by the "member for 1 year, 7 months". Are you sure you hadn't previously used the OpenID for another account and forgotten about it?

Comment: It's possible @animuson - Is there anyway to merge the two accounts?

Comment: @aneccodeal [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had mistakenly created another account some time ago.  I deleted that one and then I was able to use my gmail email address to setup a new login.

(accounts and logins on Stack Overflow/ Stack Exchange, etc. seem very confusing.)