# How do I add Google or other OpenID access to my current StackExchange account?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-exchange, openid, google-openid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

I originally created my account with StackExchange and did not want it tied to anything else such as Google, Facebook, Yahoo, etc. However, I would now like the convenience of logging into my StackExchange account through Google, but without having to create a new account. How can I accomplish this?

If such functionality does not exist, consider my question a feature request.

Comment: I hope my question is picked on on search engines and leads to the other question, because that one was not listed as a similar question.