# How to change from OpenID to Facebook login?

Tags: support, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

Currently login using MyOpenID and this is the only collection of sites I used that with. Would prefer to switch to Facebook authentication. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Forget this - found it in the user preferences screen. Now both Facebook & openid associated with this account.