# Is it possible to change the log-in Email address?

Tags: support, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

My present log-in email is getting flooded with  lot of spams. I was thinking of abandoning  it and go for a new one. Is it possible to change the Log-in email addresses of my SE account without affecting it in any way?