# Is my account available when yahoo.com.cn email service shutdown?

Tags: support, email, yahoo

as yahoo.com.cn email service will shutdown in the coming future, I use yahoo.com.cn email to register my stackoverflow account, so I want to know if my account will be available or not after yahoo.com.cn email service closes?

Comment: You can [change/add your openid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/187824).

Comment: @hims056, what's openid? can you tell me how to change/add? I don't find on this site.

Comment: See the link given in my earlier comment

Comment: Why don't you just start using another email provider now, if you know your current one is going to be shut down soon?

Comment: @himes056, I just add a google email account as my new openId, thanks.