# After adding additional logins, profile data not reflecting on the new account

Tags: support, merge-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I used to log in into stackoverflow using my myopenid profile.However, heeding the warnings given about myopenid, I finally created and added a stackexchange account to my profile using add more logins. Both the accounts showed up perfectly in the login info section.
However, when I signed out and logged in using my new stackexchange accoount, it didnt reflect the stats and information from my myopenid account. How to merge the account data?

Comment: i meant the stats that that i had accumulated on my other account, my questions and other stuff...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: You can choose "I need to merge user profiles" [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). :)

Comment: @Vigbyor that's outdated, the form has been merged to the main form [here](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) when you choose the relevant option. Consider updating your answer as well, as the link there just redirects.

Comment: None of that account merging should really be necessary, assuming that you just added an additional OpenID provider, as described in the question and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers). The only case where you'd need to merge two separate accounts is if you'd already used that OpenID to register an account.

Comment: yes as i mentioned i had used my myopenid account to register on stackoverflow...