# How to convert an account from Yahoo to an OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

Every time I login, it is through my Yahoo account. Is there a way to convert it into an OpenID type account?

Comment: See this question: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo is also OpenID provider, when you login and choose Yahoo account, there is such request behind the scenes:

```
https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth?openid.claimed_id=...
```

So no need or way to "convert" it.

You can add another OpenID provider if you like though, it's explained clearly in [this faq entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/152859).