# How to migrate a Google login to a StackExchange login?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts

I first joined the StackExchange network by signing up on StackOverflow with my Google account.

Then I joined some other sites of this network, and I decided to stop using my Google account to login.

I want to have a proper StackExchange account in order to login even if I delete my Google account.

I already check `my profile > my logins > add more logins > More logins options` but you could not add a **StackExchange login** from there.

How do I create a StackExchange account that will link all the sites I already joined?

Comment: Related bug report: [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol).  The option to add a SE login used to be there.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a workaround. I simply **logged out**, then I **signed up, creating a StackExchange account and using the same e-mail as my Google account**.

The StackExchange account has been successfully created, no conflict. My profile was intact, all my sites has been linked.

*Moreover, but I don't really know why... my Google login also seems to have been removed in the operation.*

Comment: It wasn't exactly removed; both logins essentially resolve to the same ID: your email address. If, for instance, you had a Facebook account associated with that same email, you could log in using *that as well* - it's in effect one credential that can be verified using multiple providers.

Comment: @Shog9 OK but I meant my Google login completely vanished from my logins list.