# Logged in on my dad's PC to edit his question, and I lost all my rep on S.O.?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Check out my history:

[image: High green marks, programming tools up.]

1. You can see I'm working in code (git, bash, multi-lingual, Java, Construct+Python, browser hacking, NPP, mathematics, lots of contacts).
2. And I have 84.2% positive rating in my recent reputation history.
3. I re-visit questions for up votes (edit my work and continue to research issues).

Well, there was some recent unusual behavior on my English.SE account.  I imagine there was unusual activity on Stack Overflow  Still, SO is such a useful programming tool, I'd hate to have to re-organize my question history to the browser level.

Doesn't it seem unproductive to ban a positive, high-contributing member for a full year?

Programming is my actuation, and I spend 90% of my free time reading manuals.  I will never stop programming.  I may not be a good fit for a position at someone else's company, but I do well for the open-source community as my own boss.  Requesting all bans be lifted.

Comment: So you were suspended on SO. A year ban does seem excessive for accidental sockpuppetry (if that's what you're claiming the issue is; you post is sheds more heat than light). Given that, I suspect you were suspended for some other reason. Did you check the email address you have associated with the suspended account? You should have an email from the mods detailing exactly what the problem is. Oh, and excise from your question all the distracting faff about mental institutions and your mad programming skills. Trust me when I tell you it's doing you more harm than good.

Comment: You weren't suspended for sockpuppetry, you were suspended because we suspected your account has been compromised. Please read and reply to my private mod message. It should still appear in your Notification feed.

Comment: I don't understand *"I imagine there was unusual activity on SO"*. Did you log in to SO from a sockpuppet account or not? How many times? Did you upvote or downvote your own or other people's questions/answers from multiple accounts? Facts, please. It's different if you were the innocent victim of an account takeover (which seems to be what you and Madara are saying), versus intentionally sockpuppeting to manipulate votes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspended you.

The reason was that we suspected that your account has been hacked into. The suspension was meant to protect your account. Please reset your credentials and reply to the mod message I've sent to you. You should still be able to get to it through the notification menu.

Comment: Oh.  Thank you.  I appreciate that very much, sir.  Madara hc

Comment: Side question: What are the blank areas?

Comment: Not working: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240193/changing-my-account-login-credentials

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: Okay Cool.  I've sent a response and altered my account.  Sorry for the hassle.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Madara already explained the issue to you. Just some side notes:

- Only moderators and SE employees can help you out of a ban: we can support your case, but only they can restore your account;
- Don't take this kind of stuff to Meta. Not only can't we help you, but it will often bring other users to check your account and possibly downvote bad or mediocre posts of yours. This is not what we want for you;
- Your reputation, badges and all other things that were taken from you during a suspension will be restored when your suspension is lifted.

Comment: Hey Patrick: that's cool, but the method for negotiating a lifted suspension isn't intuitive.  I'm searching google for 'how to reset my password' and such, just so I can try to follow the directions....

Comment: I see you just found it, didn't you. Good luck!