# How can I use my SE OpenID to log into other sites?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid, myopenid

I want to post a comment at someone's blog.  The author doesn't allow anonymous commenting.  I am offered the opportunity to log in using OpenID.  Supposedly, as a StackExchange user, I have an OpenID.  But I can't figure out how to use it to log in for the purposes of leaving a comment.

I found https://openid.stackexchange.com/ but that didn't help.

Here's what it looks like when I try to log in at the blog:

[image: comment form at livejournal]

The blog is hosted at livejournal.

I filled out the form, and put `aparente001.myopenid.com` in the first box that presented itself.  (I got this idea from http://openid.net/start-using-your-openid/.)  Then another box presented itself, with help text to put in a url, so I put in `https://openid.stackexchange.com` (as advised at https://openid.stackexchange.com).  Here's the error message I got:

> Cannot Complete Login
>
> Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.

**Update**:

I have attempted to follow the helpful instructions kindly provided by @journeymangeek.  I went to the [Stack Exchange OpenID page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), and clicked on "Use your own URL to log in".  I copied the link provided on the second line, as Journeyman showed in the screenshot (the code that starts with `https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/`).  I filled out the comment form at livejournal.  A step or two later, my `openid.stackexchange.com/user/etc` code was auto-entered into a key input box.  It was rejected as not being a link, so I inserted `https://` in the beginning.  The submission did not get stuck; but I got a new error message:

> naive_verify_failed_network: Could not contact ID provider to verify response.

Is this a problem at SE, OpenID, or livejournal?  Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The link they have given is wrong

You'll need to retrive the openid url for your account from the [Stack Exchange OpenID page](https://openid.stackexchange.com).

Login, check your profile page, and click on the link "Use your own URL to log in".

It'll give you a bit of HTML code

[image]

You need to copy the link on the *second line*

Paste that in as the openid URL and it should ask for permission to use those credentials to log in (That's as far as I went for *ranty* reasons, but it certainly should work after that)

<sub>(This is nearly identical to the process of adding or readding SE openID to your own account, so keen readers would notice the instructions are very similar to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295987/135565))</sub>

Comment: Thank you.  Not working yet, but progress has been made.  See update.