# Switch from OpenID to a Stack Exchange login

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

When I started using Stack Exchange sites several years ago, I logged in using Google since I wasn't sure I wanted yet another login. Well, at this point I value my Stack Exchange identity more than my Google identity, and I'd like to sever the connection.

I know you can add logins in the `My Logins` section of your settings, but I don't see a way to "add" the Stack Exchange login option I see in the new sign up screen.

Can this be done?

Comment: Related: [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you go to "Add login" from your logins, you can always enter the OpenID provider's URL in the text box provided in the "More login options". For Stack Exchange the URL is *openid.stackexchange.com*.

[image: More login options - openid.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Thanks, seems like that should be more intuitive. Maybe a button or something?

Comment: @Lance honestly I think it's a bug that there's no button for it there, since there is one when you initially login, and well, it's Stack Exchange's OpenID.