# Add Stack Exchange icon to the "more login options"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page, stack-exchange-openid

icons for popular sites appears with "more login options" but SE is not there.  I can "manually enter" my stack exchange OpenID URI if I can figure out what it is, but any question I can find on that either has an incomplete or obsolete answer.

Since the UI keeps changing, maybe "How do I find my SE OpenID?" should be a FAQ.

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is change the login e-mail from one that doesn't really exist to one that can actually send and receive.  The oddly round-about method, I'm told, is to reset password from the new address, then add the old login to it.  But the steps to do both I found in answers that no longer match the current UI, i.e., citing links and buttons that aren't there.

Comment: If someone with the privileges wants to take my word for it that user:4911647 and user:163632 are both me, go ahead and merge... :-)

Comment: Related: [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol)

Comment: And also related to solve your duplicate account problem: [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I am retracting my duplicate vote simply because this is the first 
"Feature Request" on MSE asking for this feature that I can find.  But there is a work-around offered in: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers)

Answer (score 4):

Logging in with the full Stack Exchange OpenID URL is certainly possible, but not really something we want to encourage simply because it's confusing for anyone who's not exactly up on what OpenID is or how to find that URL. It is also a primary provider, and not one we're going to hide behind another click.

For the purpose of logging into our Q&A sites with StackId, email/password is the best way to do so:

> [image]

I'm shopping around the idea of replacing the `you@example.org` placeholder text with something like `your Stack Exchange OpenID email` to see if that'll alleviate the confusion with existing users, although in all honesty, it seems like folks are adjusting fine to the new UI as time goes by.