# How can I change my Stack Exchange login email?

Tags: support, questions, email, stack-exchange-openid

I have already changed my email via one of Stack Exchange's sites, and it has been changed on all other sites as well. However, **I can only log in with my old email address.**

I don't use any third-party OpenID providers to log in. I just want to use the Stack Exchange login with a different email. How do I change my Stack Exchange login email?

Comment: How did you change your email via one of Stack Exchange's site? I can't even figure out how to do that. Heck, I can't even figure out how to log out!

Comment: That's not a duplicate, as this question is how to change the Stack Exchange login email. The OpenID is just one of various possible ways logins, a google account is other and and an email / password pair is another.

Comment: **Actual** answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers

Comment: As this was the first Google result and will be for many other people: the posted link above me by @ThatBrazilianGuy is still up to date in April 2021 and works even for plain email registered users. Unanswered is, how to really remove old emails as pointed out in the answer there, trying to log in with the old email will prompt a dialog to create the account again even after it has been deleted.

Comment: HOW TO: First go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current and **add the new email** address by clicking on "Add more logins ..." - set a password too. Then confirm the link in the email sent. Afterwards remove your old email address.

Answer (score 55):

1. Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com and create a new account
2. On that same page, click `Use your own URL to log in`
3. Copy the link that looks like `https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/xxxx-yyyy-etc`
4. Edit your logins at one of the Stack Exchange sites, such as https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me — this will affect all Stack Exchange sites:
   [image: screenshot]
5. click `add more logins...` and select `More login options`
6. paste the link at the bottom
7. if you want, go back to `my logins` and remove the old email address

Comment: I thought OpenID was supposed to make logins *easier*, not vastly more complicated, confusing, and unwieldy. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: One of the most difficult email changes I have ever done. The answer above seems to be outdated, you need now: 1. Go to https://openid.stackexchange.com and register a new account, 2. login on the same page after email confirm, 3. click on the hardly to see "Use your own URL to log in" at https://openid.stackexchange.com/user and take the link from "openid2.local_id" 3. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add and paste it there. Confirm. Done. ... gosh :/

Comment: @Synetech I guess Stack Exchange is thinking that developers can handle "complicated, confusing, and unwieldy". I vote for setting this kind of OpenID the default login experience for Facebook, iPhone, or Android.

Comment: Thanks @KaiNoack your steps helped me change my login... for others, here is a link that works to disable your old login: http://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me

Comment: What a load of crap! This has literally taken me about 25minutes to change an email address!

Comment: Are you kidding me...

Comment: thanks @Wes all I needed was this link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/me
10 seconds and done: added new email and removed old one :)

Comment: I don't see an option to create an account on openid.stackexchange.com, was it removed?

Comment: Is this still accurate now that OpenID is no longer supported? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/216712

Comment: At the date of today the link of @wasil is all we need

Comment: I don't see "create new account" on that page? Thanks

Comment: @wasil: Please post that as an answer.  That's the real answer...

Comment: I tried @wasil 's answer and I almost became unable to login. I wonder how others saying "worked" and for me it doesn't.

Comment: @Adam the question is locked as there is a more up to date answer at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers (commented below the question above) that works in April 2021. I wanted to post an updated answer but saw that the linked answer really works for once :D

Comment: I can't delete my old email!!!!!!

Comment: This took way more effort than necessary, I went through four or five pages to change a single piece of information about my account.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2023. I truly can't believe how bad this is.