# Why does my account disappear after I change the login email?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, email

I found this question about changing the login email for Stack Exchange [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247605/how-can-i-change-my-stack-exchange-login-email).

So I create another account with Google and log out and tried to add it to my account Munucial (mail@munucial) and later it was gone!

I tried to log in with the Google account it said the user's name is Munucial, but all my questions and reputation points are gone!

Why? And how can this be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contact us](/contact) link to send in a support ticket with all the details - which email address was on your old account, which new email you were trying to add, etc. We'll take a look at what happened and fix it up for you.