# Is the email address under "Edit email settings" different than the email address under "Your logins"?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

Stack Exchange's login system is confusing me terribly.

I just want to change my account's email address; the one I use to log in to sites like Stack Overflow.

When I go to My Profile -> Settings, I see two different areas with an email address.

1. Settings -> Edit email settings -> Email address (under "Your Communities")
2. Settings -> My Logins (in the list of logins)

If I understand correctly, to change the email address I use to sign in I actually need to create a new account (!) and then add that to the My Logins section. Is that correct?

If so, what is the other email address setting for?

Can someone explain this please? Judging by [the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247606/329357) when I searched "stack overflow change email address" I am not the only person who is deeply confused and frustrated by all this.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple login options associated with a particular account (which may be email+password, signing in via a Google account, a Facebook account, etc.). You can add a login option by going to the "[Your logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)" page, then scrolling to the bottom and clicking the "Add more logins..." button. That'll take you to a new page where you can specify the login option you want to add – which can be an email+password, Google account, Facebook account, etc.

However, the email address you specify under "[Edit email settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current)" is the one that the site uses to contact you (e.g. for whatever email notifications you opt in to). You can only have one email address set here at any given time. (The email address you've set here doesn't necessarily need to match your login options, as far as I know.)

Comment: So if I want to change the email address I use to *log in*, I have to register a brand new account? Seems kind of insane.

Comment: @WackGet: ...No, you don't need to register a new account for that – you just have to add it as a new login option for your existing account, as I said. Click the "Add more logins..." button, enter the email address and password you want to use to log in, and click "Add login".