# How to add standard account access to Google Account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts, google

I do have a Stack Exchange account that I log in using Google auth. I'd like to provide myself with alternative access to my account, i.e. without Google - a separate login/password, Google-independent, for the same account. I've been searching for that and found only merging accounts, but that's precisely not the case.

What can I do to add standard login/password access to my Google-dependent account?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's the one! Anyway, it's very strange that I need to do a workaround (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704) instead of SO providing such a feature...