# Unable to add new login method

Tags: support, login, network-profile

I've tried adding both a new Gmail account and Stack Exchange account to my existing account, however it just seems to redirect me to nowhere.

For example, I am currently using in-private browsing, signed in to my old Gmail which is letting me use SE, however when on my network profile I click `My Logins -> Add more logins -> Login with Google` it then just redirects me to my network profile page?

I then created a new stack exchange account with the Gmail account I'm trying to add and this time I tried `Login with Stack Exchange` instead, I then type the credentials but them I am asked `Do you want to logout and in with this OpenID?` and if I click Login it just logs me in to the new account without joining them together.

What am I doing wrong?

**Video of problem**
https://vid.me/g3XZ

Comment: I think that you can't add logins from the network profile since it's not a real profile. Try adding per-site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just tried from super user, again the GMail option redirects me to my profile and I can't see an option for Stack Exchange account...?

Comment: Hmm... guess a dev better have a look then, hopefully soon. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I added a video of the problem, hopefully someone takes note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are logged into only one Google account and Stack Exchange already has authorization to use that account, Google will immediately redirect you back to us as a successful login attempt. Since that Google account is already attached to your profile, nothing happens once you reach us again. I checked your account history, and Google is using the account already connected to your profile each time you're attempting to log in. There are a couple ways around this on Google's end though:

1. Sign out of *all* Google accounts before attempting to add a new one to your Stack Exchange profile. This will force Google to ask you to log in and you can manually change which Google account you wish to use.
2. Manually sign into multiple accounts on Google. If you have more than one account currently signed in, Google will always ask you to select which account you want to proceed with, regardless if one is already authorized or not. You can easily do this by visiting any Google page, clicking on your profile picture in the upper right corner, and then clicking the "Add Account" button in the dropdown.

As far as I know, only Google does this automatic redirect thing (I've never encountered anyone complaining about any other service doing this), and you're definitely not the only person who has become extremely confused about this odd system they have in place.

---

As for connecting your new Stack Exchange OpenID account to your previous account - it's [admittedly somewhat difficult to add OpenID accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704). Once you've already created the account, there isn't really any way for you to easily attach it to another account without our assistance. I'd encourage anyone with separated SE OpenID accounts to just [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) for assistance in merging, as it will be far easier to get it done that way.

I've gone ahead and merged your two network accounts together so that everything is all in one place.

Comment: Many thanks for explaining and merging for me.