# How do I change which Google account used for login?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-accounts, openid

Going through [this process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/193412) and accounting for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263337/193412) I am unable to change my Google account associated with my profile.

Even going through this process:

1. Open incognito chrome
2. Log into my SE account using primary Gmail
3. Sign out of Gmail
4. Resign into other Gmail
5. Attempt to change account via profile page

This results in being able to successfully click through the entire process but the new account is not listed on the page.

I have also tried the following, which has resulted in me being stuck with Facebook as login:

1. Add Facebook login
2. Remove initial Gmail login
3. Attempt to add Gmail login

Neither of these results in any actual change to my login. However, now I am stuck with my login as a Facebook login as I cannot add back the original Gmail login *or* the new one.

The email address for my Facebook account appears identical to my initial Google login looking at the logins screen. However, that is different than my profile email address (which would match the second Google account I've been attempting to use).

Comment: The apps (both android and iOS) have trouble logging in with Google lately, I see lots of bug reports. Maybe related? Some change Google made on their end, which SE didn't properly apply in their code yet?

Comment: You actually have another account registered already using the email you're trying to add. Normally our system would attempt to auto-merge these, but it silently fails because you are a member of a Team. Someone will take care of this for you soon.

Comment: @animuson is that an account I should be aware of? Or is it a Team account?

Comment: @animuson why no answer explaining this?