# Possible to just use an email address for account

Tags: support

I'm currently using a google openid that will soon no longer be available, so I need to remove it as a login. I can see where to remove it on my profile but the only option is to replace it with another form of openid.
Is it possible to just use an email address?

If not I assume I could simply add another google openid and remove the original one without causing any problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to use an email address and password combination rather than authenticating with a third-party service, you can always add a Stack Exchange OpenID to your account. The process for doing so is [admittedly somewhat complex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704), but it is certainly possible to create and attach one to your account.

If you run into any problems (like you get it created and it *doesn't* attach to your account), just use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page and we'll get it attached to your account properly. Once you have the SE OpenID, you can remove the Google login if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I will add another OpenID.

Comment: SE's decision to use (and keep using) OpenID is one of the things I really like - I originally came to SF not as a sysadmin but because I'd heard it was using OpenID.  It maximises your control over your own identity management, and i'm pretty sure it'll be the right way for you to go.