# I've lost access to my SE email and password; do I have options?

Tags: support, login, account-recovery

A while ago I lost my password database (and since then do the obvious and have encrypted backups...) and as a result I lost my password to most websites and I was unable to recover one of my emails. I decided just now to see how the SE site works on mobile (I use the app exclusively), but I just realized which email this account is associated with!

Is there any way I can get the password or/and email of this account changed?

If not should I try to use this account for as long as possible, or just start over now? I'm finally at a happy place with my account and it'd be a shame to start over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you no longer have access to the email address, then there is no way to reset the password for it if you have forgotten it.

You can, however, add a new credential to your account so that you can continue using it without that email address by editing your profile and then clicking on the [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) link in the left-hand menu, assuming you still have access to the account itself (which you seem to have). If you wanted to add a new email/password login with a different email, please read the [instructions for doing so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704).

If you cannot get into the account, you'll need to use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form so we can give you instructions and so you can send us some information to verify you are the owner of the account.